# Python Selenium Compose email fail

Tags: python, email, selenium

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from setuptools.py31compat import unittest_main

username = "robertredrain@gmail.com"
password = ""
tomailid = "robertredrain@yahoo.com"
emailsubject = "robertredrain@yahoo.com"
mailbody = "Great! you sent email:-)" + "\n" + "Regards," + "\n" + "Robert"

class send_email(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.baseUrl = "http://mail.google.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html"

    def test_Login_Email(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.baseUrl)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.find_element_by_id("gmail-sign-in").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("Email").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id("next").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_id("Passwd").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("Passwd").send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_id("signIn").click();

        #Verify login
        if "Gmail" in driver.title:
            print("Logged in sucessfully !!!" + driver.title)
        else:
            print("Unable to loggin :-( " + driver.title)

        time.sleep(5)


    def test_Compose_Email(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        driver = self.driver
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div").click()
        #time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("vO").send_keys(tomailid)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("aoT").send_keys(emailsubject)

        driver.find_element_by_class_name("Am").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("Am").send_keys(mailbody)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Send']").click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close();

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I try to do "COMPOSE email", but got the error "raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div"}"
Could someone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

*Make it simple* and locate the "Compose" button *by text*:

```
//div[. = "COMPOSE"]
```

Comment: looks like if do not use "def test_Compose_Email(self)" it will work well. Do  you know how to detail it with the function?

Comment: @robertredrain sorry, cannot understand, can you elaborate more?

Comment: I mean if I delete the function title, the compose can works fine. if I keep the function, it could not work again. do you know if how it can work with the function title?  Working code:#def test_Compose_Email(self):
        #time.sleep(10)
        #driver = self.driver
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='COMPOSE']").click()
        time.sleep(5)

Comment: @robertredrain sure, cause for every test you get a clean browser profile started. At the time `test_Compose_Email` is executed, you are not logged into gmail and selenium cannot find the Compose button.

Comment: so how to connect the test_Compose_Email function?

Comment: @robertredrain you should put your "logging into gmail" logic into the `setUp` function.

Comment: do you have any suggestion how to do it? I am new in Python unittest.